# hector slam and arduino help please

Tags: arduino, slam, navigation, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i install ros kinetic on raspberry pi3 and i configure kinect with hector slam and all work well.
now i want to implémante arduino to make a robot with 2 wheels, i install rosserial and i don't know how can i relate hector slam with arduino to control motors.
i know that hector slam provide odometry.
can you help me please? i don't know how can i control motors with hector slam

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239736/hector-slam-and-arduino-help-please/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hector_slam is used for mapping, not autonomous control. You could try taking a look at [hector_exploration_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_exploration_planner).

Normally the way it works is a path planner will publish a set of velocities for the robot as a whole. You will need to write a node that will use the inverse kinematic equations for your particular robot to determine the individual wheel velocities required to achieve the desired motion.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-07-19**:
thanks, i write a node arduino that publish rpm and subscribe to cmd_vel with ros serial, and i can control my robot with teleop_twist_keyboard. and also i create a package with hector slam that visualise a map.
now i want to add odometry to hector_slam for autonomous mapping .
what can i do please?

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-07-19**:
Hector_slam does not require odomtry

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-07-19**:
so what can i do please? i dont found explication on hector navigation

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-07-20**:
Ok, so you've built a map using hector_slam and now you want to autonomously drive around that map? Is that right?

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-07-20**:
nn i can build a map with hector slam but i move kinect with my hand.
now i create a robot with 2 motors and arduino (i can controle manually motors with teleop_twist_keyboard) and i want to navigate with this motor autonomously to create a map.
can you help me for this?

**Comment by [RoSPlebb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27287/rosplebb/) on 2016-07-21**:
@Emilien I replied to you on another similar post you created.

@Icehawk101 Youve helped me before and i really appreciate your help. Could you please provide your insight on a couple things on hector navigation please?

http://answers.ros.org/question/239850/hector-navigation-questions/